# Execute animation when the element enters the viewable area in angular11

Tags: angular, animation

I want to trigger an animation when the window scrolls and the element enters the visible area, instead of using click events or buttons to trigger

[click me , stackblitz address](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-alain-setup-hmbhxu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

The animation is triggered when the current page loads, how can I make the card to trigger the animation when scrolling to the visible area

Comment: You need to track the scroll and apply that CSS when the scroll reaches that position.

Comment: perhafs you're interested in "intersection observer" https://blog.bitsrc.io/angular-maximizing-performance-with-the-intersection-observer-api-23d81312f178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) 
    doSomething(event:any) {
            if (window.innerWidth > 700) {
                    if (window.pageYOffset >= 357) {
                            this.activeTopClass = true;
                            this.topSection = "slide-left";
                    }
             }
     }
    
     // HTML Code

     <div *ngIf="activeTopClass" [attr.class]="topSection"></div>
     
     // The other option could be to perform something like this
                @Component({
            selector: 'app-open-close',
            animations: [
                trigger('openClose', [
                    // ...
                    state('open', style({
                        height: '200px',
                        opacity: 1,
                        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
                    })),
                    state('closed', style({
                        height: '100px',
                        opacity: 0.8,
                        backgroundColor: '#c6ecff'
                    })),
                    transition('open => closed', [
                        animate('1s')
                    ]),
                    transition('closed => open', [
                        animate('0.5s')
                    ]),
                ]),
            ],
            templateUrl: 'open-close.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['open-close.component.css']
        })
        export class OpenCloseComponent {
            isOpen = true;
            toggle() {
                this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
            }
        }

       // HTML CODE
       <div [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'" class="open-close-container">
        <p>The box is now {{ isOpen ? 'Open' : 'Closed' }}!</p>
       </div>
       // YOu can change the value of isOpen to true or false by 
       // tracking the scroll position
```

Comment: Is there a way not to use css?

Comment: I have updated something you can have a look at it.

Comment: This method is more suitable for a single element, but in my example it is a list, so each element needs to be judged whether it enters the visible area, and the animation state is set separately

Comment: I use `scroll even`+`@ViewChildren`+`QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLElement>>`+`AnimationBuilder`，but effect  too bad